# Approximation of $|\phi^{\pi}-\pi^{\phi}|$

Tags: inequality, approximation, pi, golden-ratio

> Show that $$|\phi^{\pi}-\pi^{\phi}|\leq \operatorname{T},$$
>   where $\phi$ is the golden ratio and $\operatorname{T}$ the [Tribonacci Constant](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TribonacciConstant.html)

Using a calculator, we have $|\phi^{\pi}-\pi^{\phi}|=1.839144\cdots$ and $\operatorname{T}=1.83929\cdots$.

I have tried to make the problem more general using functions, but I would like to know if there are tricks to solve this problem.

Comment: Should the problem be approximated by hand?

Comment: This is almost $\pi$ times the largest root of $1430 x^5-1032 x^4+1126 x^3-421 x^2-196 x+56=0$ . This has not be done by hand. The relative error is $5\times 10^{-19}$%.

Comment: Have fun with https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=express+1.83914498114821536268005941391846+through+Pi+and+GoldenRatio

Comment: You could try looking at the polynomial $p(x) = x^3 - x^2 - x - 1$ for $x = \alpha =  \pi^\phi - \phi^\pi$ -- then showing that $\alpha$ is less than $T$ amounts to showing that $p(\alpha) < 0$.